# Drop down in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, drop-down-menu

I am using Libgdx. I need a drop down list in a pop up window. I have already tried the same. My code is:

```
    tf=new SelectBox(new String[]{"1","2","3"}, skin);
    tf.setY(labelQuestion.getY()-labelQuestion.getHeight());
    tf.setX(labelQuestion.getX());
    tf.setWidth(70f);
```

Comment: And how is that not working for you?   Does it not compile?  Not run?  Not show what you expect?

Comment: It compiles, but the drop down list does not show.

Comment: Are you sure its being drawn?  (Its added to a Stage and the stage is being rendered?)  If so, try giving it a fixed height to see if maybe its being shrunk down to nothing?

Comment: sometimes when I face these kind of problems with scene2d.ui a call to widget.pack() corrects it, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Right...from your question (and the following comments) it's not really clear to me what your issue is. However here (because maybe it helps you) an outline of how your drop-down menus are supposed to be looking:

```
// Set up the SelectionBox with content
Object[] blob = new Object[2]; 
blob[0] = new Label("Some random text that", skin); 
blob[1] = new Label("isn't being displayed!", skin); 
final SelectBox<Object> sb = new SelectBox<Object>(skin); 
sb.setItems(blob); 


//For easier handling of Widgets
Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true); 
table.center();

table.add(sb);
stage.addActor(table);
```

This will display the list of OBJECTS. If you wanted the actual contents of the TextFields you would have to create a SelectionBox of Strings, then fill it with the actual strings of the objects.

To actually detect which object is being selected you have to use something like this:

```
sb.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
    System.out.println(((Label) sb.getSelected()).getText());
  }
});
```

Again...not sure what your question was exactly. But I hope that whatever it was, I just answered it :)

Edit: Sorry for reviving this zombie. I didn't see the date was so long ago. But I hope this helps anyone finding it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
    public static String[] SERVER_NAMES = {"localhost", "Home IP"};

    final SelectBox<String> selboxServer = new SelectBox<String>(game.assets.skins.get("default"));
    selboxServer.setItems(SERVER_NAMES);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).